# Scheduled Mailings not sending in Civi 5.71.2 after upgrade from 5.70.2

Tags: civimail, flexmailer

Upgraded to Civi 5.71.2 from 5.70.2.  Scheduled mailing (a monthly newsletter) to send immediately.  The Send Scheduled Mailings Job runs, but does not finish (and does not show any sort of error message in the Scheduled Jobs Log or the full Error Log).

I restored back to 5.70.2, and scheduled a mailing, and it sent as expected. The only changes to the environment were the core CRM version---no extension changes since they were all up to date before upgrading to 5.71.2.

Based on warnings I found in the Error Log (below), it looks like something happens with fireWalkBatches and the scheduled job never gets to fireComposeBatch or fireSendBatch on 5.71.2.

Platform is PHP 8.1 / Wordpress.

**Warnings in Error Log**

**5.71.2** - I found the following warnings show up at the time the Send Scheduled Mailings job runs:

```
[warning] \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event is deprecated. Consider using \Civi\Core\Event\GenericHookEvent. For more information see https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/usage/symfony/#events Caller: Civi\FlexMailer\FlexMailer::fireWalkBatches
[warning] \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event is deprecated. Consider using \Civi\Core\Event\GenericHookEvent. For more information see https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/usage/symfony/#events Caller: Civi\FlexMailer\FlexMailer::fireRun
```

**5.70.2** - Whereas the Error Log shows the following warnings for the Send Scheduled Mailings job under 5.70.2:

```
[warning] \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event is deprecated. Consider using \Civi\Core\Event\GenericHookEvent. For more information see https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/usage/symfony/#events Caller: Civi\FlexMailer\FlexMailer::fireSendBatch
[warning] \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event is deprecated. Consider using \Civi\Core\Event\GenericHookEvent. For more information see https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/usage/symfony/#events Caller: Civi\FlexMailer\FlexMailer::fireComposeBatch 
[warning] \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event is deprecated. Consider using \Civi\Core\Event\GenericHookEvent. For more information see https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/usage/symfony/#events Caller: Civi\FlexMailer\FlexMailer::fireWalkBatches
[warning] \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event is deprecated. Consider using \Civi\Core\Event\GenericHookEvent. For more information see https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/usage/symfony/#events Caller: Civi\FlexMailer\FlexMailer::fireRun
```